# What is new() function here?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, proxy-pattern

I've been learning design patterns and I saw such a method call from a class :

```
class Client: SubjectAccessor {
    static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine("Proxy Pattern\n");

        ISubject subject = new Proxy();
        Console.WriteLine(subject.Requesy());

        subject = new(); //Here is what I am asking
        COnsole.WriteLine(subject.Request());
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a `subject = new();` call there and I am wondering whether it is creating a new instance of `Proxy` or something else. I've not found anything related to this.

Your help is much appreciated.

If you need, I can paste the whole code or actually it is written on a book so I need to write it down here.

Thanks.

Comment: where'd you see this? looks like a typo

Comment: C# 3.0 Design Patterns - Judith Bishop Page 27

Comment: It is a type as stated. Following http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/6da66b58-2f52-4023-a874-c3e5a4bbca05 shows that it should be subject = new ProtectionProxy();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is a typo in the book. There is no current version of C# in which that is valid (it should raise a "Type expected" compiler error). Without context it is impossible to know what it *should* be.

Comment: Then, what should it have been? `subject= new Proxy();` ?

Comment: @Braveyard - I can't tell without context; it could be meaning to show a *decorator*, for example, in which case it could be something like `new SomethingOtherType(subject)`

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK it's wrong, and that code won't even compile.

The new keyword in C# can have only the 3 meanings described in this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Really like the context of the link. Thanks for it.

Answer (score 4):

I was the technical editor of that book; I have a copy right in front of me now. My copy says:

```
class Client : SubjectAccessor { 
  static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine("Proxy Pattern\n");

    ISubject subject = new Proxy();
    Console.WriteLine(subject.Request());
    Console.WriteLine(subject.Request());

    ProtectionProxy subject = new ProtectionProxy();
    Console.WriteLine(subject.Request());
```

Now, there is an error here; the variable "subject" has been declared twice.  Apparently I did not catch the error when I reviewed the book. (The correct thing to do here is to remove the type from the second declaration of "subject").

However, that is *not* the error that you are reporting.

Are you *sure* that is not what your copy says?  I have the December 2007 first edition; what edition do you have?  Perhaps someone attempted to correct this error in a later edition and messed it up? My guess would be that someone tried to correct the error by removing *both* mentions of the ProtectionProxy type from the erroneous line rather than removing the *first* one.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I have the december 2007 edition.

Answer (score 2):

That would be the proxy class. never seen such syntax before tho. Best not to use such things as it will only reduce readability..

Comment: On the last word, definitely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see how that compiles. "new" in this context is the new operator and this always expects a typename per C# syntax.

Comment: That was also what I knew. It should be typo anyways.